# Prevent systemctl restart mosquitto.service from resetting Dynamic Security

Tags: mosquitto

I'm trying out the Dynamic Security module for mosquitto and everything seems to work fine as long as I never `systemctl restart mosquitto.service`.  After install mosquitto and enabling the Dynamic Security module, I ran these two commands:

```
mosquitto_ctrl dynsec init /etc/mosquitto/dynamic-security.json steve
systemctl restart mosquitto.service
```

Then I was able to create a user, role, subscribe and publish to a topic like this:

```
mosquitto_ctrl -u steve -P Pass1234 dynsec createClient john0
mosquitto_ctrl -u steve -P Pass1234 dynsec createRole role0
mosquitto_ctrl -u steve -P Pass1234 dynsec addClientRole john0 role0 1
mosquitto_ctrl -u steve -P Pass1234 dynsec addRoleACL role0 publishClientSend pizza allow
mosquitto_ctrl -u steve -P Pass1234 dynsec addRoleACL role0 subscribeLiteral pizza allow 

mosquitto_sub -u john0 -P Pass1234 -t pizza
# then open a second terminal window and do this:
mosquitto_pub -u john0 -P Pass1234 -t pizza -m 'hi'

# result is the word `hi` appears in the first/original terminal window
```

I can repeatedly publish and subscribe to topics with the `john0` user on the `pizza` topic.

However, the moment I have to reboot my server or if I run a `systemctl restart mosquitto.service`, then the `john0` client no longer exists.

How do I prevent the `john0` user and all the roles and access privileges from disappearing after a `systemctl restart mosquitto.service`?

---

**EDIT**

Here's my `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf`

```
persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

allow_anonymous false
per_listener_settings false

plugin /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mosquitto_dynamic_security.so
plugin_opt_config_file /etc/mosquitto/dynamic-security.json
```

Also, in my `/etc/mosquitto/dynamic-security.json`, the only record taht exists is he one for `steve`.  I do not see any other clients in the `dynamic-security.json` file.

---

**EDIT**

Also, it seems if I manually edit the `/etc/mosquitto/dynamic-security.json`, it does NOT immediately take effect.  I need to run `systemctl restart mosquitto.service` in order for the changes to take effect.

So I guess now my question is specifically how do I add clients and roles such that it meets all these criteria:

1. I can add them during run time and they immediately take effect without a `systemctl restart mosquitto.service`.
2. After a `systemctl restart mosquitto.service`, that the clients and roles still exist (ie. they are not deleted)

Comment: Please edit the question to include the full contents of your mosquitto.conf and any other mosquitto configuration files you're using. Also, are the changes you're making appearing in `/etc/mosquitto/dynamic-security.json`?

Comment: @romkey - i updated with the mosquitto.conf file .  Only the `steve` client ever appears in the `/etc/mosquitto/dynamic-security.json`.  The `john0` never seems to appear

Comment: @romkey - I also updated my question to show that if I manually edit the `/etc/mosquitto/dynamic-security.json`, I need to `systemctl restart mosquitto.service` in order of things to take effect.  But my challenge is I don't want to restart the mosquitto service every time i add a user.

Comment: It's not expected to take effect until you restart - it's only read on startup. You may be having a permissions issue - mosquitto may not be able to write to `/etc/mosquitto`. State is meant to be stored in `/var/lib/mosquitto` - try changing the config file's location to `/var/lib/mosquitto/dynamic-security.json` and make sure it's owned by the user mosquitto is running as. Then restart mosquitto and do the tests you tried again.

Comment: @romkey - your answer worked!  I moved my dynamic-security.json to a different location, chown to the same user as my mosquitto service, and chmod 755.  Now I can use mosquitto_ctrl command to add new users and roles AND the dynamic-security.json is updated so that the next time the system reboot, the changes will be retained.

Comment: Glad it helped! I finally wrote it up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mosquitto was configured to store its dynamic security state in `/etc/mosquitto/dynamic-security.json`.

Unfortunately, `/etc/mosquitto` is frequently not writable by mosquitto, for security reasons. State is generally meant to be stored in `/var/lib/mosquitto`, which Mosquitto is able to write to.

To fix this, change the configuration to read:

```
plugin_opt_config_file /var/lib/mosquitto/dynamic-security.json
```

If you have an existing `dynamic-security.json` file in `/etc/mosquitto` you can move it to `/var/lib/mosquitto` and retain whatever is currently in it:

```
mv /etc/mosquitto/dynamic-security.json /var/lib/mosquitto
chown mosquitto /var/lib/mosquitto/dynamic-security.json
chmod 700 /var/lib/mosquitto/dynamic-security.json
```

The `chown` line makes sure it's owned by the user `mosquitto` - if you run `mosquitto` as a different user, change this line to be the user you run it as.

The `chmod` line makes sure that only the file's owner (and root) can read the file. Even though the passwords in the file are encrypted, we don't want to make it any easier than necessary for an attacker to access it.

Comment: Thanks! I feel dumb because I didn't figure this out on my own

Comment: Not that many years ago it would have worked! Definitely not dumb, it's a very easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to permission issues for mosquitto

You can just simply do

```
chown mosquitto /etc/mosquitto/dynamic-security.json
```

After this when you use **mosquitto_ctrl** commands.
It will be visible in the json file.