# unable to use mosquitto_pub with dynamic security to create new users

Tags: mosquitto

My question is how come I can't use `mosquitto_pub` to create new users?

I can't seem to use the `mosquitto_pub` command to create new users in Dynamic Security based on instructions given by this readme file:

https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/master/plugins/dynamic-security/README.md

In terms of what I tried, I successfully made a new user and role first with `mosquitto_ctrl` command just to ensure dynamic security was working.  Then I tried the `mosquitto_pub` command, which failed.  Let me provide details for both the mosquitto_ctrl and mosquitto_pub scenarios below.

**SUCCESS: Using mosquitto_ctrl**

I created a role like this:

```
mosquitto_ctrl -u steve -P Pass1234 dynsec createRole role0
mosquitto_ctrl -u steve -P Pass1234 dynsec addRoleACL role0 publishClientSend pizza allow
mosquitto_ctrl -u steve -P Pass1234 dynsec addRoleACL role0 subscribeLiteral pizza allow
```

Then I made a user like this:

```
mosquitto_ctrl -u steve -P Pass1234 dynsec createClient user0
mosquitto_ctrl -u steve -P Pass1234 dynsec addClientRole user0 role0 1
```

I open one terminal and put in this command:

```
mosquitto_sub -u user0 -P Pass1234 -t chocolate
```

I open second terminal window and put this command:

```
mosquitto_pub -u user0 -P Pass1234 -t chocolate -m 'I love chocolate'
```

The result is that the first terminal windoow prints 'I love chocolate'.

**FAIL: Using mosquitto_pub**

Since the `role0` already exists, I figure I can create a new user and just assign `role0` to that user.
I run this command:

```
mosquitto_pub -u steve -P Pass1234 -t '$CONTROL/dynamic-security/v1' -m '{"command": "createClient", "username":"user1", "password":"Pass1234", "roles":[{"rolename":"role0", "priority":1}]}';
```

Then I try this command

```
mosquitto_sub -u user1 -P Pass1234 -t chocolate
```

The result is `Connection error: Connection Refused: not authorised.`  If I do a `systemctl restart mosquitto.service`, both `user0` and `user1` get the same connection not authorized error.  Throughout all the experiments above, the `/etc/mosquitto/dynamic-security.json` only shows the client `steve` and the `admin` role that I initially and manually set up after fresh installation of mosquitto 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.  This command worked:

```
mosquitto_pub -u steve -P Pass1234 -t '$CONTROL/dynamic-security/v1' -m '{"commands":[{"command": "createClient", "username":"user0", "password":"Pass1234", "roles":[{"rolename":"role0", "priority":1}]}]}';
```

Basically I needed to wrap my command with `{"commands": ... }`.

AND I also had to make sure I remedy this situation here:

[Prevent systemctl restart mosquitto.service from resetting Dynamic Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71197601/prevent-systemctl-restart-mosquitto-service-from-resetting-dynamic-security)